# Wordpress: margin in the post text respecting size images

Tags: css, wordpress, post, margin

Hello I want to apply it to the text margins ticket, but when I apply the value here **.post{}** moves me pictures of size and also become smaller.

I tried to apply this to the pictures **.post img{}** and it works, I can put the images to a certain size and text entry give margins, but the problem is that not always will post images of the same size, how could give margin the text without affecting the images? thanks

PS: These values ​​apply to the style.css of my theme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to put a margin to .post{} and the opposite value to .post img{}.

For example:

```
.post {
   margin-left: 10px;
}
.post img {
   margin-left: -10px;
}
```